# How to access the Camera itself in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, camera, android-camera

I am creating an application that allows you to take pictures. I wonder how I can access the camera itself. To take the photos I use the package `image_picker`, but with that I can only take the photos, and I have no influence on the camera itself. For example, I would like to adjust the size of the camera screen, turn the flash on automatically, and indicate some sort of guideline of where the object to be photographed should be. See the photo below for an example.

Can someone tell me how I could make those adjustments in the camera itself, instead of just taking a picture with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera#-readme-tab-), it provides even more features such as making snapshots, recording video, and accessing the image within the app itself.